# How to autocomplete a property?

Tags: autocompletion, properties

I've replicated [org mode's example](https://orgmode.org/manual/Property-Syntax.html), except I didn't manually fill out the value for key `Publisher` under `Goldberg Variations`. How do I get a prompt for autocompletion?

```
* CD collection
  :PROPERTIES:
  :NDisks_ALL:  1 2 3 4
  :Publisher_ALL: "Deutsche Grammophon" Philips EMI
  :END:
** Classic
*** Goldberg Variations
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Title:     Goldberg Variations
    :Composer:  J.S. Bach
    :Artist:    Glenn Gould
    :Publisher: 
    :NDisks:    1
    :END:
```

Comment: `C-c C-x p` on the `Publisher` property, `RET` to confirm the property name (it's already defaulted to `Publisher`), `TAB` to get completions on the property value. I'm given the three choices from `Publisher_ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments: `C-c C-x p` on the Publisher property.